# Running a function on EC2 through API Gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway

I want to link Amazon API Gateway to a function in my EC2 instance but am finding little online about hwo to do this.

Currently I have set up the API call as follows:
[image]

Can anyone shed any light as to how I could connect the API call to my python function called 'test.py' in the root folder of my EC2 instance

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you might be able do this with the [AWS Run Command](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/run-command/) service, but it is a weird way of doing things. The AWS Service Proxy proxies the AWS API. So telling it to proxy the AWS EC2 service exposes the AWS API to manage EC2 instances. Managing EC2 instances includes things like creating and deleting servers. It does not include things initiating an SSH connection to the server, logging into the server, and then running a command on the server.

The standard way to run a script on a server via API Gateway is to expose that script via a web server on the EC2 server, and then have API Gateway hit the appropriate URL.

Answer (score 2):

API Gateway cannot directly execute a Python function sitting on the file system of your EC2 instance. API Gateway can only interact with EC2 instances via http/https endpoints. If you must run you Python function on an EC2 instance then you'll need to run a web server or application server on your EC2 instance and set it up to execute your Python function when it gets a request on a specific path.  Then set-up your API Gateway http integration endpoint to use that path.

If you just need to execute this Python function and don't necessarily need it to run on this EC2 instance, then you could set-up a Lambda function containing your Python function.  Then set-up your API Gateway to call the Lambda function.  Using the Lambda approach means that you don't need to manage the EC2 instance.  Also, for low-volume use cases, Lambda can be much more cost effective than running a dedicated EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by invoking System manager "Send Command" from API Gateway Integration Request. EC2 instance has to be managed by SSM and instance Role associated with your EC2 instance.